# Angular ngShow sidebar sliding animation issue

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I'm trying to animate a toggle-able sidebar so that it slides open and closed, and I can't seem to get the animations to work whatever I do. I think I'm getting confused with how I'm supposed to apply animations to ngShow/ngHide elements.

I've included an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/chiggerchug/m6ahk463/62/

**EDIT:** Link updated, menu now pauses before closing, but no animation is applied.

Here's an example of my css which is applied to the element that is being toggled:

```
  .animate-show-hide.ng-hide {
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
  }

  .animate-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
  }
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Have you injected ng-animate in your module coz in your plunker you havent angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);

Comment: Whoops. Updated the link. (Still not working though, its now pausing then hiding the element without animating it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code of yours is working. You just have to change your animation class

```
@keyframes myChange {
    from {
        width: 250px;
    } to {
        width: 0;
    }
}

.animate-show-hide.ng-hide {
  animation: 0.5s myChange;
}
```

**Fiddle**:https://jsfiddle.net/m6ahk463/64/

**Updated Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/m6ahk463/66/

Comment: If you want to see a better animation. change .animate-show-hide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
 transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

Comment: Your jsfiddle mod hasn't animated the menu, it still pauses. I'm looking for something along the lines of this: https://codepen.io/ScintillaLuz/pen/HxzED

Comment: I have updated the answer. Will this suffice. What you are looking for won't work as expected for the way you have written ur HTML

Comment: There are now two different animations in the two fiddle. See if these are the animations you are looking for?

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Thanks very much for your help! I've updated the fiddle to make sure the text in the menu disappears with the div bounds. https://jsfiddle.net/chiggerchug/m6ahk463/68/

Comment: Awesome!! Glad to be of help :)